# (Inside ListView.builder) Every time I press the ExpansionTile, the trailing icon of the ExpansionTile changes also on other ExpansionTiles

Tags: flutter, animation, trailing, expansion-tile

I have ListView.builder which returns ExpansionTile. Inside of this ExpansionTile, I used trailing with row widget. When I use row inside of the trailing, I lost the animation effect, therefore I used AnimatedRotation widget. But now every other ExpansionTile's trailing icon changes its direction.

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour? I just want the animate the trailing icon of the ExpansionTile that I pressed to change.

Note: I aim to put trailing with text and icon with proper turn animation. If there are any other solutions rather than using trailing with row I am open to recommendations.

Here is my code

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 15,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ExpansionTile(
            iconColor: Colors.red,
            textColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
            childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
            expandedCrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            tilePadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 0,
              horizontal: 10,
            ),
            leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            trailing: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Text("60.00₺"),
                AnimatedRotation(
                    turns: _isExpanded ? .5 : 0,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                    child: Icon(Icons.expand_more)),
              ],
            ),
            onExpansionChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _isExpanded = value;
              });
            },
            title: Text(
              "22.04.2022",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Color(AppColors.blacktextcolor),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            subtitle: Text("Bekliyor"),
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  "Talep Eden",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 13),
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                  "Sertan Yıldız",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ),
             
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
```

https://gifyu.com/image/S3J5c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to store the state of the expanded widgets in a list.

Generate a list with a false or true state for all expansion tiles and then use that state based on the index for each tile.

Take a look at the following code below:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  
 List<bool> _isExpandedStateList =
    List<bool>.generate(15, (int index) => false);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 15,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          bool _isExpanded = _isExpandedStateList[index];
          return ExpansionTile(
            iconColor: Colors.red,
            textColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
            childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
            expandedCrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            tilePadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 0,
              horizontal: 10,
            ),
            leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            trailing: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Text("60.00₺"),
                AnimatedRotation(
                    turns: _isExpanded ? .5 : 0,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                    child: Icon(Icons.expand_more)),
              ],
            ),
            onExpansionChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _isExpandedStateList[index] = value;
              });
            },
            title: Text(
              "22.04.2022",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            subtitle: Text("Bekliyor"),
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  "Talep Eden",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 13),
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                  "Sertan Yıldız",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ),
             
            ],
          );
        },
      );
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Thank you. I understand your logic. You created a list of booleans and with the index property of listview.builder every ExpansionTile has a unique bool value in your list. Therefore they can behave individually. It really helped me and it works great!

Comment: @doclock4715 I'm happy that you understood. But, I can see you made an edit but if you closely look at my code you will find that the edit was not required.  I have declared ` bool _isExpanded = _isExpandedStateList[index];`  for individual items under the itemBuilder so the animation will just work fine.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed that part. My bad. Thank you again :D